# git pull origin master returns "Already up-to-date" even though it isn't

Tags: django, git, digital-ocean

I'm using `git pull origin master` to pull my Bitbucket repo onto my Digital Ocean Django server directory (which already has some folders for Django like `env` and `static`) . When I do this it says `Already up-to-date.` but the repo didn't come through? I'm not sure if I'm misinterpreting what `git pull` does but I assumed it took the contents of mu repo and merged with my current directory. If this isn't true, can somebody explain what other command I should do to achieve this?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here. Where is it set up to pull from (`git remote -v`)? Did you push changes from your local copy to that remote? How?

Comment: `Already up-to-date` means the local branch has included the whole history of the branch in the remote repository. Here's one of the methods to verify the result. `git fetch origin master && git log -1 FETCH_HEAD --pretty=%h` returns a commit C1. `git log -1 --pretty=%h` returns a commit C2. `git merge-base HEAD FETCH_HEAD` returns a commit C3. If C3 is equal to C1, then it's expected to see `Already up-to-date` after `git pull origin master`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman my mistake I should have clarified that. I've already done `git remote add origin <my_repo.git>` I created the Bitbucket repo by committing my local repo (not my Digital Ocean server) to it.

Comment: It's still not clear. If you wanted to get a copy of your bitbucket repo on your server, why didn't you simply clone it rather than creating a new repo and adding a remote?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because you can't clone into a non-empty repository. My Digital Ocean server repo is not empty as it has files/folders set up for a Django project which I need to keep, e.g. `env`, `static` and `manage.py`. So I want to simply add the contents of the Bitbucket repo *next to* the files already on the DO server.

Comment: But why aren't those in your repo? Certainly static and manage.py should be, I don't know what env is. Anyway, normally you would clone the repo and then add any other non-tracked directories.

Comment: Yeah I can certainly add `manage.py` and `static` into the repo. `env` is the virtual environment I've been building through the Digital Ocean setup for a Django project. Am I able to just move them from my server to my Bitbucket repo, delete them from the server, then `git clone` the whole project back to my server? Is that the best course of action you think?

Comment: Please include the repo init steps in the question so that others may reproduce your problem. What does `git status` tell? If it shows all files as deleted, the repository was probably done through `git init .`, `git remote add ...`, `git fetch` and `git reset <branch>` which wouldn't include any point where the working copy files are actually checked out. A simple `git checkout .` should then work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the origin at the first place, from where you want to pull the git repo. If not, then you should set the origin, first.

```
git remote add origin <link to your git repository>

for eg., git remote add origin https://github.com/gitaccname/gitproject.git
or, git remote add origin git@github.com:gitaccname/gitproject.git
```

After that, you can pull your git repository into whichever server you like, using the command.

```
git pull origin master
```